# c++ oop programming

Tags: c++, linker-errors

**project1.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Bicycle.cpp"
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    bool runP = true;
    do {
    Bicycle object();
    char oType;
    cout << "Would you like a (B)icycle, or (A)nimal? E for Exit\n";
    cin >> oType;

    if (oType == 'B' || oType == 'b') {
        int seat, wheels;
        string brand;
        cout << "How many wheels does the bike have?\n";
        cin >> wheels;
        object().setWheels(wheels);
        cout << "How many seats does the bike have?\n";
        cin >> seat;
        object().setSeats(seat);
        cout << "What is the brand of the bike?\n";
        cin >> brand;
        object().setBrand(brand);
        object().toString();
    } else if (oType == 'A' || oType == 'a') {
    } else if (oType == 'e' || oType == 'E') {
        runP = false;
    }

    } while (runP == true);
    return 0;
}
```

**Bicycle.h**

```
#include <string>

class Bicycle {

private:
    int wheels;
    int seats;
    std::string brand;
public:
    Bicycle();
    Bicycle(int w, int s, std::string b);
    int getWheels();
    int getSeats();
    std::string getBrand();
    void setWheels(int w);
    void setSeats(int s);
    void setBrand(std::string b);
    void toString();

};
```

**Bicycle.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Bicycle.h"
#include <string>


    Bicycle::Bicycle() {
    }
    Bicycle::Bicycle(int w, int s, std::string b) {
    }
    int Bicycle::getWheels() {
        return wheels;
    }
    int Bicycle::getSeats() {
        return seats;
    }
    std::string Bicycle::getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }
    void Bicycle::setWheels(int w) {
        wheels = w;
    }
    void Bicycle::setSeats(int s) {
        seats = s;
    }
    void Bicycle::setBrand(std::string b) {
        brand = b;
    }
    void Bicycle::toString(){
        std::cout << "Bike object has: Brand: " << getBrand() << ", wheels: " << getWheels() << ", seats: " << getSeats() << "\n";
    }
```

**stdafx.h**

```
    #pragma once

#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
```

*Error:*

```
1>------ Build started: Project: project1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  Bicycle.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>  Compiling...
1>  project1.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>  Skipping... (no relevant changes detected)
1>  Window.cpp
1>  Animal.cpp
1>project1.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Bicycle::Bicycle(void)" (??0Bicycle@@QAE@XZ) already defined in Bicycle.obj
1>project1.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Bicycle::Bicycle(int,int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (??0Bicycle@@QAE@HHV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) already defined in Bicycle.obj
1>project1.obj : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Bicycle::getWheels(void)" (?getWheels@Bicycle@@QAEHXZ) already defined in Bicycle.obj
1>project1.obj : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Bicycle::getSeats(void)" (?getSeats@Bicycle@@QAEHXZ) already defined in Bicycle.obj
1>project1.obj : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall Bicycle::getBrand(void)" (?getBrand@Bicycle@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) already defined in Bicycle.obj
1>project1.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Bicycle::setWheels(int)" (?setWheels@Bicycle@@QAEXH@Z) already defined in Bicycle.obj
1>project1.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Bicycle::setSeats(int)" (?setSeats@Bicycle@@QAEXH@Z) already defined in Bicycle.obj
1>project1.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Bicycle::setBrand(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?setBrand@Bicycle@@QAEXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) already defined in Bicycle.obj
1>project1.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Bicycle::toString(void)" (?toString@Bicycle@@QAEXXZ) already defined in Bicycle.obj
1>project1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class Bicycle __cdecl object(void)" (?object@@YA?AVBicycle@@XZ) referenced in function _wmain
1>C:\Users\Hash\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\project1\Debug\project1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: where is your question?

Comment: Typically people show that they put some effort into the resolution of their problem, listing what they've tried. Otherwise you may be met with the assumption you didn't try to resolve anything and just copy-pasted your code/errors into a web form and hit submit.

Comment: Just wondering - how does setWheels work for a real bicycle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure instead of

```
#include "Bicycle.cpp"
```

you want

```
#include "Bicycle.h"
```

With the first, everything in Bicycle.cpp gets copy-pasted into project1.cpp and you get duplicate definitions with one set of bicycle functions defined when project1.cpp is compiled, and the other when Bicycle.cpp is compiled.

Answer (score 5):

`project1.cpp` should

```
 #include "bicycle.h"
```

not

```
 #include "bicycle.cpp"
```